# Numeros random cada cierto tiempo

Tags: java, random

¿Alguien sabe como generar números random cada minuto?

Ahorita solo tengo un ciclo for donde manda 3 datos nada mas, pero los manda al instante, y yo necesito que cada minuto me arroje un numero random.

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){      
int numero = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;      
System.out.println(numero);     
}
```

**Resultado es:**

```
56
32
49
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: te recomiendo que cuando las dudas sean de Java, uses la etiqueta de Java; pues usar netbeans no es necesario, eso es solo un IDE; aqui lo relevante es el lenguaje que usas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes valerte de una llamada a `Thread.sleep()` para introducir una espera de `n` milisegundos antes de obtener el siguiente número.

`Sleep` recibe la cantidad de milisegundos que *dormirá* el hilo desde el que se invoca antes de continuar su ejecución.

Ejemplo, adaptando tu código, podría ser:

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){      
  int numero = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;      
  System.out.println(numero);     
  Thread.sleep(60000); //60000 milisegundos son 1 minuto
}
```

La salida será la misma, pero tu programa entregará cada número 1 minuto después del anterior.

Un defecto de el código que te envío es que luego de entregar el último número, el programa esperará un minuto antes de terminar. Esto no es necesario, te queda como ejercicio a ti adaptarlo para que no haga esa espera, si así lo deseas.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho.